# Can you add the "measure" tool to model builder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, measurements

I am wondering if there is a way to add the measure tool, usually residing in the Tools toolbar, into model builder?

Comment: What is the goal/objective of what you're trying to do?

Comment: No its not really a tool that applies to model builder.

Comment: @dassouki it's a bit of a complicated answer, one piece of the project is measuring the distances of a set of points (representing houses) to the nearest point to the west (representing intersections). I am having trouble figuring out a way to instruct the measurements to go to the West rather than just measuring to the nearest intersection point, as there are closer points that are to the east.

Comment: You are talking in the singular so why not just select that "west" point then run the generate neat table tool. As all GIS systems honor selections only that point would be processed despite there being nearer points?

Comment: Or for that matter run GNT on all the points, which will give you the angle to the point, and filter out of the results - first those where the angle doesn't match 'west', then summarizing to find the minimum distance going west. It's unclear whether you're concerned with straight-line or network distance, and if network distance whether roads (in which case network analyst) or pipes (in which case geometric network, with traces, and since there's already flow direction your 'west' issue is solved). But the short answer is no - the measure tool is an interactive user tool, not a GP tool.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is "No".

It sounds like you're wanting to find the nearest intersection to the west of each house. If you want the nearest intersection following the road, you'll need the Closest Facility tools in the Network Analyst extension. If you want the nearest intersection in a straight line, a possible solution mightbe:

- create lines from each house to each intersection
- use the `arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management` tool to add fields containing  the *lenth* and *line_bearing* attributes to the newly created lines dataset.
- select the lines with *line_bearing* greater than 180 and less than 360, and use the Summary Statistics tool to find the MIN value.

*edit:* these steps could be placed into a python script tool which could then be accessed from model builder

Comment: Adam is right. I was gonna say @eplanner, if you need to specify directionality, you need something like a [Bearing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/bearing-distance-to-line.htm) and combine it with your Near results somehow. Additionally, new in version 10.3, the [arcpy.Geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm) class has several methods that relate to angular measurements if you were inclined to script a solution - e.g. angleAndDistanceTo, pointFromAngleAndDistance.